# Join tables that do not have an association defined in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables in my DB, Car, accidents and ValueAnalysis. The first one stored the information about the car itself, the second one about the accidents it was involved in and the last one about the analysis it went through to check for its value (price).

Accidents has a FK to car, just as ValueAnalysis.

```
Car <-- Accidents
 ^
 |
ValueAnalysis
```

But VA doesn't reference accidents and accidents doesn't reference VA.

In this specific page, I would like to perform a query and get information about the car, the accidents and the analysis.

I tried this:

```
@Analysis = Analysis.joins(:car, "INNER JOIN accidents a ON (a.month = value_analysis.month)").where("car.plate = '#{params[:plate]}' ")
```

So I will receive a plate as a parameter and I would like to get information about the car, accidents and ValueAnalysis.

This code works at the moment, the only thing that is missing is that I do not know how to access the information about the accidents:
@Analysis[0].car retrieves the car information, but @Analysis[0].accidents doesn't exist.

Is there any way I can perform this join query without adding the association in the model?

Edit: there are some suggestions that I should use analysis[0].car.accidents or similar. Accessing this way is a very nice approach, but in this case I want to correlate accidents and analysis ti show in a chart. So it would be great if I could have in a row the car, the analysis and the accident that correlates to that analysis (I know the correlation because the dates will be the same).
If I could have this query working, I would not need any extra logic in my app to find the correlated accident to each analysis.

PS: Why accidents and analysis do not have a FK? Because the analysis will happen every day, disregard of accidents or not. If an accident happens, I would like to know the information about the analysis of that day.

Answer (score 0):

As per your association diagram, `car` is related to `accidents` with 1-M relationship.

You can access the `accidents` for a particular `car` using using `@Analysis[0].car.accidents`

Comment: That is true, but the query I would ideally run would join the accident and analysis by the date (they are ALWAYS equals). So I would have a row where I already know which analysis correlates to which accident. 
This is important because I am building a chart where I want to correlate accidents and analysis. If I access the property the way you propose, I would need to have extra logic in my application to find the accident that correlates to a given analysis.